# Kubernetes Container Command

Tags: kubernetes, cat

I'm working with Neo4j in Kubernetes.
For a showcase, I want to fill the Neo4j in the Pods with initial data which i can do with a cypher-file, I'm having in the `/bin` folder using the cypher-shell.
So basically I start the container and run `cat bin/initialData.cypher | bin/cypher-shell`.
I've validated that this works by running it in the `kubectl exec -it <pod> /bin/bash` bash.
However, no matter how I try to map to the `spec.container.command`, it fails.
Currently my best guess is

```
spec:
  containers:
    command:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - |
          cd bin
          ls
          cat initialData.cypher | cypher-shell
```

which does not work. It displays the `ls` correctly but throws a `connection refused` afterwards, where I have no idea where its coming from.

edit: Updated

Comment: Why does it fail specifically? Can you include the rest of the spec? Do you run this as an init-container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out what my problem was.
I did not realize that the commands are not linked to the initialisation lifecycles meaning the command was executed, before the neo4j was started in the container.
Basically, using the command was the wrong approach for me.

Answer (score 1):

You did valid spec, but with a wrong syntax.

Try like this

```
spec:
  containers:
    command: ["/bin/bash"]
    args: ["-c","cat import/initialData.cypher | bin/cypher-shell"]
```

Update:
In your neo4j.conf you have to uncomment the lines related to using the neo4j-shell

```
# Enable a remote shell server which Neo4j Shell clients can log in to.
dbms.shell.enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
dbms.shell.host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
dbms.shell.port=1337
```

Comment: It kinda got me closer to a working solution, however I'll always get a `Connection refused` afterwards. I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: @Urr4 I have also updated my answer accordingly,  check it out.

Comment: Oh, that's confusing, since I can exec into the pod and run the command without problems. Just when I'm doing it in the `command` section, it fails. I'm gonna try your solution

Answer (score 0):

Exec seems like the better way to handle this but you wouldn’t usually use both command and args. In this case, probably just put the whole thing in command.